# ページ表示後に意図しないGETリクエストが発生する

Tags: python, django

こんにちは。最近Python、Djangoの学習をし始めた者です。
ページ表示後の意図しないGETリクエストの原因についてお伺いさせてください。

#### 事象

作成中のWebアプリケーションのトップページを表示した際、画面の表示自体は問題なく行われる(GET 200)のですが、ターミナルで以下の通り意図しないURLへのアクセスおよび404エラーが発生します。
DBから取得したデータの表示も意図したとおりに行われています。
/nullへのリクエストが発生する原因について理解したく、調査方法についてご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
[27/May/2022 10:01:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2515 Not Found: /null
[27/May/2022 10:01:39] "GET /null HTTP/1.1" 404 2622
```

#### 試したこと

以下が原因でないことの切り分けを行いました

- テンプレート：
  テンプレート拡張をしており、対象の画面を構成する全2つのテンプレートそれぞれについて、htmlの内容を空白にしてみましたが解消しませんでした。
- クラスベースビュー、関数ビュー：
  現在クラスベースビューにしているのですが、関数ベースビューに変更しても解消しませんでした。

#### ソース

当該画面に関わるurls.py, views.pyを共有します。

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
]
```

views.py

```
class Dashboard(View, LoginRequiredMixin):
    def get(self, request):
        study_records = StudyRecord.objects.filter(recorder=request.user).order_by('-created_date')[:DASHBOARD_RECORD_DISPLAY]
        return render(request, 'mystudy/dashboard.html', {'study_records': study_records})
```

##### 環境

Python 3.10.4
Django 4.0.4

Comment: @ydddp さんの回答を踏まえると、ブラウザの拡張機能をすべて無効にして（例えばシークレットモードなど）アクセスしてみるのがよいかも知れません。

Answer (score 3):

自分の場合は、Chrome拡張機能のマウスジェスチャーツール「crxMouse Chrome™ Gestures」が原因でした。
この拡張機能がhtmlの<bodyに`style="cursor: url("null"), default;"`を挿入するから、エラーが表示されるのです。